# Display image in modal window from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML I have several articles. Each article contains one image, and if you click one of them, a modal window appears. So my question is, how can I make the image from the article show in the modal window?

If you want to check my code check this:

```js
 var article = document.querySelectorAll("article");
    var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    var cross = document.querySelector(".cross");
    var contentModal = document.querySelector(".modal .contentModal img");
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("article img");

    var funcModal = function (value) {
        article[value].addEventListener("click", function () {
            modal.style.visibility = "visible";
            modal.style.opacity = "1";
            contentModal.style.src = image;
        })
        cross.addEventListener("click", function () {
            modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
            modal.style.opacity = "0";
            modal.style.transition = "opacity 1s";
        })
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
        funcModal(i);
    }
```

```css
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                                Commons



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
*,*:before,*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                                Header



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
header ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
header li {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
header a {
    color: #34495e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
header a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                            Section > article



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
article {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
article img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.col-20 {
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
}

/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                             Fênetre modale



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
.modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.modal i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #34495e;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.contentModal {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.contentModal img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="cf">
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20">
            <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
        </article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <article class="col-20"></article>
        <div class="modal">
            <i class="fa fa-times cross"></i>
            <div class="contentModal">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I think you're asking how to set the source of the image in the modal to be the same as that in the thumbnail? You'll want to get a reference of the image inside the click event of the article, rather than outside of it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan : Yes I am looking for a technique, so that the image of my thumbnail is the same for my modal window. I wish you hope understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're setting the `image` variable once, before anything is clicked (and setting it to a list of images). You want to set that variable every time an article is clicked, to the image of the article that was clicked.

```js
var article = document.querySelectorAll("article");
    var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    var modalImage = modal.querySelector('img');
    var cross = document.querySelector(".cross");

    var funcModal = function(value) {
      article[value].addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.style.visibility = "visible";
        modal.style.opacity = "1";
        // here, "this" will be a reference to the article clicked
        var image = this.querySelector('img');
        modalImage.src = image.src;
      })
      cross.addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
        modal.style.opacity = "0";
        modal.style.transition = "opacity 1s";
      })
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
      funcModal(i);
    }
```

```css
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                                Commons



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                                Header



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

header ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
header li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
header a {
  color: #34495e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                            Section > article



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

article {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
article img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.col-20 {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                             Fênetre modale



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

.modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.modal i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #34495e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contentModal {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.contentModal img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="cf">
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20">
    <img src="img-content/france/1.jpg" alt="">
  </article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <article class="col-20"></article>
  <div class="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-times cross"></i>
    <div class="contentModal">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hum, right I understand. Thanks you for take a part of your time !